# the method 'Any' is not supported when MaxProtocolVersion is less than '3.0'

Tags: c#, wcf

I have recently upgraded my project from .NET Framework 4.5.1 to 4.7.2 and added a WCF service reference in the project.

When I add service reference to .NET Framework 4.5.1 project the auto-generated code in reference.cs file has below constructor method

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
        public abc(global::System.Uri serviceRoot) : 
                base(serviceRoot, global::System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3)
```

But when I added service reference to .NET Framework 4.7.2 project the auto-generated code in reference.cs file has below constructor method

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
        public abc(global::System.Uri serviceRoot) : 
                base(serviceRoot)
```

The version parameter doesn't exist in inherited base class of .NET Framework 4.7.2 project. This is causing the below error during run time

> the method 'Any' is not supported when MaxProtocolVersion is less than
>   '3.0'

When I add the parameter manually and run the project it works completely fine. But I can't add the parameter manually as it is auto-generated file and gets updated once i update the service

I have looked at WCF service .svc file and the InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config) method has below line of code.

```
config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
```

Thanks in advance